# How to implement Console app with VSIX Extension

Tags: c#, machine-learning, keras, console-application, vsix

I am working on loading .H5 Machine learning model with `Keras.Models.Model.LoadModel(path + "issue_classifier_w2vec_new.h5");` in C#. This loading supposed to be performed on click event of a button (Typically a menu button which was added through VSIX Extension).

When I run a fresh console application in visual studio 2019, It runs perfectly. But when I run the same code in VSIX Project or on btn click event, It shows **BadImageFormatException** and **Python runtime exception**. I think it is not able to find an environment for python in the experimental window (a window that opened by executing a VSIX project wherein the extension will be installed)

I think it is mandatorily required a console for executing python libraries but on clicking a button, it is not able to be loaded. Please help me out if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ML model (Keras .h5 model) I am trying to load is based on 64-bit **only**. And the place (.vsix project in visual studio) where I am trying to load this is a vsix plugin project which is based on 32-bit **only**. 
That's the reason,  why I am not able to load a model into vsix project. And same is the reason for **BadImageFormatException**.

It is not possible to do this without degrading or upgrading (matching) both the versions.

Answer (score 1):

There's some pretty good details on this exception in the documentation covering the [BadImageFormatException class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.badimageformatexception?view=netframework-4.8).

The most common scenario where I've seen this encountered is when the calling application and the DLL are not built targeting the same architecture. The VS IDE (devenv.exe) is a 32-bit application, so I suspect you are attempting to load or invoke code in a 64-bit specific assembly.

Comment: Yes! Exactly this is the problem. I've explained this detailed in another answer. Thanks for responding.